# Java3D canvas = javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D[canvas0,0,0,0x0,invalid]

Tags: java-3d

Need some advice.

I have a self-written Java3D program that has worked for years on my computers. On my development computer (Windows10, x64 bit Intel i7 processor, ATI Radeon HD 4600 display processor), the program works well using Java3D 1.5.1 and using JRE1.8.0_131. It also has jdk1.8.0_102. I do my development with NetBeans IDE8.1.
In the past I have been able to run my Java3D programs on  my laptop (Windows10, x64 bit Intel i3, Intel HD graphics 3000). OpenGL Extensions viewer reports that I have OpenGL 3.1 (May 2016).  Also installed on this laptop is Java3D 1.5.1 (JRE) and Java JRE 1.8.0_131. Now I am getting some errors.  Here is the piece of code causing the error:

```java
    System.out.println("StarChart3Dpanel constructor : create simple Universe");
    SimpleUniverse su = new SimpleUniverse();
    System.out.println("StarChart3Dpanel constructor :  simple Universe created");
    su.getViewer().setVisible(false); //this will hide the small SimpleUniverse
                                      //window that otherwise will pop up.
    System.out.println("StarChart3Dpanel constructor: Will now create canvas");
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = su.getPreferredConfiguration();
    System.out.println("GraphicsConfig = " + gc.toString());
    Canvas3D canvas = new Canvas3D(su.getPreferredConfiguration());

    String glVersion = (String)canvas.queryProperties().get("native.version");
    System.out.println("StarChart3Dpanel constructor: GL Version = " + glVersion);
    canvas.stopRenderer();
```

And here is the System output showing the error:

```
C:\deployed\2017\starChart3D>java -jar starChart3D.jar
…
StarChart3Dpanel constructor scene has been created
StarChart3Dpanel constructor : create simple Universe
Java 3D ERROR : wglGetExtensionsStringARB not support !
 - The specified procedure could not be found.

Fallback to use standard ChoosePixelFormat.
StarChart3Dpanel constructor :  simple Universe created
StarChart3Dpanel constructor: Will now create canvas
Java 3D ERROR : wglGetExtensionsStringARB not support !
 - The specified procedure could not be found.

Fallback to use standard ChoosePixelFormat.
GraphicsConfig = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig@bc67047[dev=Win32GraphicsDevice[screen=0],pixfmt=0]
Java 3D ERROR : wglGetExtensionsStringARB not support !
 - The specified procedure could not be found.

Fallback to use standard ChoosePixelFormat.
Java 3D ERROR : OpenGL 1.2 or better is required (GL_VERSION=1.1)
javax.media.j3d.IllegalRenderingStateException: GL_VERSION
        at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline.createQueryContext(Native Method)
        at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline.createQueryContext(NativePipeline.java:2755)
        at javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.createQueryContext(Canvas3D.java:4906)
        at javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.createQueryContext(Canvas3D.java:3659)
        at javax.media.j3d.Renderer.doWork(Renderer.java:460)
        at javax.media.j3d.J3dThread.run(J3dThread.java:256)

DefaultRenderingErrorListener.errorOccurred:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Canvas3D: Non-recoverable graphics configuration error
        at javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.queryProperties(Canvas3D.java:3648)
        at starChart3D.StarChart3Dpanel.<init>(StarChart3Dpanel.java:87)
        at starChart3D.StarChart3DmainFrame.<init>(StarChart3DmainFrame.java:64)
        at starChart3D.StarChart3Dapp.<init>(StarChart3Dapp.java:26)
        at starChart3D.StarChart3Dapp.main(StarChart3Dapp.java:53)
CONTEXT_CREATION_ERROR: Renderer: Error creating Canvas3D graphics context for queryProperties()
graphicsDevice = Win32GraphicsDevice[screen=0]
canvas = javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D[canvas0,0,0,0x0,invalid]
```

The program is also failing on my x64bit laptop at work.

I have googled and seen several posts of the same issue in the 2013 timeframe.  Can someone explain what actually WHAT  happened to the Java JRE that broke the Java3D code, and also WHEN that change happened?
I know there is a JOGL out there and a 1.6 version of Java3D but was hoping for a simple fix that I could do – like new jar files on the laptop computers.   Do I need to put JOGL on my Netbeans and develop new distributables?

Answer (score 0):

At first, I think that the Microsoft GDI renderer (supporting only OpenGL 1.1) is picked instead of a better OpenGL driver provided by your GPU manufacturer. The only workaround consists in using an older JRE (< 1.8 update 60), there is a bug report about that in our bug tracker, Phil spent a lot of time in looking for a solution: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1278#c15

Secondly, sorry but don't expect any help if you go on using an obsolete version of Java3D released more than 9 years ago.

Comment: thanks.  I have seen your name associated with a bunch of Java3D work,so you are definitely the guy with the "know".   Can you point me to the best site to download the latest Java3D.  Seems like there is a 1.6.0 and a 1.7.0, but the 1.7 has different package names?   I also see JOGL and JOGAMP out there.  I am wondering just how much of a rewrite this will be for me.  If I can get something that interfaces with NetBeans, that would be great.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I confirm that hopefully Java3D 1.7 has different package names (it solves lots of troubles, especially under OS X). No rewrite is required if you stick with Java3D 1.6.0, a minor rewrite (editing package names) is required if you switch to Java3D 1.7 but as it will get Android support and as it contains some more fixes, maybe it's worth the effort. I advise you to carefully read my tutorial and this page in our wiki: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_Java3D

Comment: I did  download Java3D 1.6.0.  I successfully removed the older 1.5.1 version and compiled my code in NetBeans.  All compiles well.  I also installed JOGAMP and added the following 2 jar files to my library (I am only targeting 64bit Windows machines): gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar, jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar, and jogl-all-noawt-natives-windows-amd64.jar.  I am still getting this error at runtime:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/opengl/GL
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, maybe something important is missing. You don't have to add those 2 JARs, they contain only the native libraries whereas the interface com.jogamp.opengl.GL is another JAR in the Java libraries. Please strictly follow my instructions: https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/#download The fat JAR contains both the Java libraries and the native libraries. You only need to use the JARs I mention in my tutorial and nothing else.

Comment: By the way, there is no sane notion of "install" for a third party library. The good practice consists in adding the necessary JARs into the classpath of your software and the necessary native libraries (if any and if they aren't managed by another mechanism) into the library path of your software.

Comment: Actually, there is another problem. The OpenGL driver for the Intel HD 3000 is no longer supported by Intel under Microsoft Windows 10, it explains why Java3D complains about finding OpenGL 1.1 whereas OpenGL >= 1.2 is required and there is nothing we can do to solve this problem: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1278#c15

Comment: SUPER!   Thanks.  I ported my code over to my office machines at work and it works splendidly over there!   Case solved.   I really appreciate your help.  If you are ever in Houston,  I will buy you a beer!

Comment: You're welcome :) I hope that you won't have any trouble with the OpenGL drivers. I have already seen some good laptops with Intel i3 and Intel HD 3000, it's so disappointing when Intel doesn't provide a working OpenGL driver.

Comment: Just to install Java 3D from this https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/java-3d.html

Comment: @arthur-alunts No, this version is obsolete and unmaintained. Rather use the version I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  now I have success on my development PC, using the fat jar file. Interestingly I get no errors, but my application takes almost 1 minute to appear.  It used to take < 5 seconds.   Still, it works.    I used NetBeans and did a build/distribute, copied the results to a USB stick, and verified it still runs off the USB stick on my dev PC.   I moved it over to another 64 bit Win 10 PC that has the Intel HD graphics 3000) card. Note: OpenGL Extensions viewer reports that I have OpenGL 3.1 (May 2016) on this target PC.  But now I am getting this error message on that PC after the same ~60 seconds:

```
StarChart3Dpanel constructor: Will now create canvas
GraphicsConfig = javax.media.j3d.JoglGraphicsConfiguration@69213a37
javax.media.j3d.IllegalRenderingStateException: Java 3D ERROR : OpenGL 1.2 or better is required (GL_VERSION=1.1)
        at javax.media.j3d.JoglPipeline.setupCanvasProperties(JoglPipeline.java:8090)
        at javax.media.j3d.JoglPipeline.access$600(JoglPipeline.java:88)
        at javax.media.j3d.JoglPipeline$ContextQuerier.init(JoglPipeline.java:8719)
        at javax.media.j3d.JoglPipeline$QueryCanvas.doQuery(JoglPipeline.java:8626)
        at javax.media.j3d.JoglPipeline$QueryCanvas.access$100(JoglPipeline.java:8574)
        at javax.media.j3d.JoglPipeline.createQueryContext(JoglPipeline.java:6561)
        at javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.createQueryContext(Canvas3D.java:4609)
        at javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.createQueryContext(Canvas3D.java:3606)
        at javax.media.j3d.Renderer.doWork(Renderer.java:461)
        at javax.media.j3d.J3dThread.run(J3dThread.java:271)

DefaultRenderingErrorListener.errorOccurred:
CONTEXT_CREATION_ERROR: Renderer: Error creating Canvas3D graphics context for queryProperties()
Exception in thread "main" graphicsDevice = Win32GraphicsDevice[screen=0]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Canvas3D: Non-recoverable graphics configuration error
        at javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.queryProperties(Canvas3D.java:3595)
        at starChart3D.StarChart3Dpanel.<init>(StarChart3Dpanel.java:87)
        at starChart3D.StarChart3DmainFrame.<init>(StarChart3DmainFrame.java:64)
        at starChart3D.StarChart3Dapp.<init>(StarChart3Dapp.java:26)
        at starChart3D.StarChart3Dapp.main(StarChart3Dapp.java:53)
canvas = javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D[canvas0,0,0,0x0,invalid]

D:\starChart3D>pause
```

Comment: PS - this is the directory tree: c:\JogAmp>tree /F
Folder PATH listing for volume HP
Volume serial number is 00000052 4ACE:7312
C:.
│   java3d-javadocs-all.zip
│
├───jogamp-fat-all
│   └───jogamp-fat
│           jogamp-fat-java-src.zip
│           jogamp-fat-test-java-src.zip
│           jogamp-fat-test.jar
│           jogamp-fat.jar
│
└───jogamp-java3d
        j3dcore.jar
        j3dutils.jar
        vecmath.jar

Comment: Maybe the virus scanner looks at JOGL native libraries, it's really annoying. Sometimes, it completely prevents the software from running. If a software isn't "marked" Windows 10 compatible, the Intel OpenGL driver will go on working but if a software is "marked" Windows 10 compatible (in your case, it's the JRE), the driver will intentionally fail and use the Microsoft GDI renderer as a fallback.